# ASP.NET ActiveDirectory Federation authentication for multiple projects

Tags: asp.net, authentication, active-directory, adfs

At this point, our company is hosting multiple (internal) projects, all related to each other under windows authentication. With this - it is easy - we just set up windows forms authentication in IIS, and all of them are secured, one login required, and the user is logged in in all of them.

The main applications are as fallows:

- Client side application (built with just html/javascript). Hosts index.html for the application
- Server side application (APS.NET MVC project, but we mainly use it as a WebAPI. Client side application calls for back-end resource, Server side is usually responsible for the responses.
- Proxy application - proxies some webRequests to remote resources from client side.

Under IIS our projects look like this:

```
- Sites
  - hostname
      Client side application with 
      index.html
      all of the other front end resources
      web.config for clientside application
      - ServerSideApplication (MVC4 project)
          - its bin
          - web.config for serverside application
      - Proxy application (Strange ASP.NET project)
          - its bin
          - web.config for proxy application
```

URLS are made like this

- https://hostname/index.html for clientSide application
- https://hostname/SERVER/ for ServerSide application
- https://hostname/PROXY/ for the proxy application

Now I am tasked to enable Federation authentication for this system, and I don't have enough knowledge to connect all of this together!

I was looking at creating new MVC projects to get some examples, with selecting authentication to "Work or School Accounts" and "On-Premises". This creates an application that could work for me. But that is for a single application. What would I do with ClientSide application? Would I need to wrap it in an ASP.NET MVC project, and set the same settings as for the ServerSide application? I noticed - if I create a WebAPI project, it adds token authentication. With that, I would require additional step for client side application to obtain that token, to be sent with the requests?

How should I build this system? No need concrete code examples, some hints for finding the solution, some experience would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to authenticate with Azure AD or ADFS?

Azure AD = "Work or School Accounts"

ADFS = "On-Premises"

There are Azure AD samples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code).

There are ADFS samples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/msal/adfs-msal-web-api-web-api).

For both, you need IDP configuration for each application.

Applications are called Relying Parties (RP) and there is an RP configuration per application.

If the application calls a web API, then that is two RP.

You then configure permissions for the application to access the web API.

Find a sample similar to your use case and that will explain this in more detail.